# Computing trace of matrix

Tags: matrices, limits, matrix-calculus, trace

Let **A** be a n×n matrix such that $$[a_{ij}]_{n×n}=\frac{((-1)^i)(2i^2+1)}{4j^4+1}$$ then what is
$$1+ \lim_{n\to {\infty}}\left(tr(A^n)^{1/n}\right)$$
I cannot figure out how to calculate trace of $$A^n$$

Comment: Is there any context for this? Where does the question come from?

Comment: Are you asking about source?

Comment: Yes, but the point is thst various "hints" about how to do the question should be in your book (or whatever) in the general vicinity of the problem. The matrix is hairy enough that every little bit helps.

Comment: Could you confirm that your indices $i,j \in [1,n]$ ?

Comment: Yes index I,j belongs to [1,n]

Answer (score 4):

If $\{\lambda_k\}$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, then $A^m$ has eigenvalues $
\{\lambda_k^m\}$ and so:
$$\text{trace} A^m = \sum_{i=1}^n\lambda_k^m.$$
If these eigenvalues are non-negative reals, then you can easily show that:
$$\lim\limits_{m\to\infty}\sqrt[m]{\lambda_1^m+\dots \lambda_n^m} = \max\limits_k \lambda_k.$$
what remains to be done is to find the eigenvalues of your matrix which I do not see an immediate formula for.

Comment: In fact you must write max $|\lambda_k|$.

Answer (score 4):

Answer complementing the answer of @dezdichado.

In fact this matrix is the product of the (column) vector $U$ with coordinates:

$$(-1)^i(2i^2+1), \ \ \ \ i=1 \cdots n$$

with the line vector $V^T=$ with coordinates

$$\frac{1}{4j^4+1}, \ \ \ \ j=1 \cdots n$$

Therefore $A=UV^T$ is a rank 1 matrix. As such, it has eigenvalue $0$ with multiplicity $n-1$, and a nonzero eigenvalue that is plainly the trace, therefore the real number:

$$\lambda=\sum_{i=1}^n a_{ii}=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{(-1)^i(2i^2+1)}{4i^4+1}$$

which has a closed form expression due to its alternate signs yielding a telescoping behavior (observation made by Dezdichado):

$$\lambda=\dfrac{-2n^2-2n-1+(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^2+1}$$

Remark: the result obtained is the square of the so-called spectral norm of $A$.

Comment: oh very nice! I knew the matrix looked too "artificial" to be a difficult problem.

Comment: and I think the sum telescopes because: $$4i^4+1 = (2i^2-2i+1)(2i^2+2i+1)$$ and then the fraction is decomposed partially to sum of the two products, which then telescopes due to alternating sign I think.

Comment: You are right. I will write the answer.

Comment: @user1551 I agree. I don't know why I have written "positive" intead of "real".... This is confirmed by the expression I have given.

Comment: So basically the limit comes out to be -1/2 and the result becomes 1/2.

Comment: @S.M. It depends on the interpretation of letter $n$. For me, it was two different $n$ : a fixed $n$ for the first expression and a variable $n$ in the second. If it is the same $n$ you are right.